# How to make argument Non-Null only on some certain condition in GrpahQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I am trying to implement some small graphql experiment with Ruby on Rails.

Let say I have a type `User`, I want to query an user either by `id` or `email`. So when email is provided, id can be absent and vice versa.
Is there a build-in way to achieve this instead of writing a manual check inside the resolve function?

Current state of the code is similar to below where both `id` and `email` need to be presented.

```
UserField = GraphQL::Field.define do
  name("User")
  type(Types::User)
  argument :id, !types.ID
  argument :email, !types.String
  resolve ->(object, arguments, context) { ... }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't look to be a native way of doing this.

Make them both optional and then throw an error if they're both set or both null?

An alternative would be to have two endpoints: user, and user_by_email